# How to deploy bugzilla with psgi on dotcloud?

Tags: perl, cgi, bugzilla, dotcloud, psgi

I want to deploy bugzilla on dotcloud, but the perl environment is psgi.

The [doc](http://docs.dotcloud.com/services/perl/) said I must use "modules to add PSGI hooks to legacy CGI or FastCGI applications".

I found [CGI::Emulate::PSGI](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/CGI-Emulate-PSGI-0.14/lib/CGI/Emulate/PSGI.pm) module but could not figure out how to do it.

I am a Python programmer and have no experience in Perl.

Comment: Late addition: http://www.activestate.com/blog/2011/12/running-bugzilla-cloud

Answer (score 0):

I had partial success with bugzilla-4.0.2 on a local openSUSE. I don't think Bugzilla will be suitable for cloud deployment in the short term because of its large amount of manual setup necessary. Follow the instructions referenced from `docs/en/html/index.html`, then run

```
plackup -MPlack::App::CGIBin -e'Plack::App::CGIBin->new(root => ".")->to_app'
```

and visit `http://localhost:5000/index.cgi`. The static files are missing, e.g. stylesheets. Something like along the lines of

```
plackup -MPlack::Builder -MPlack::App::Directory -MPlack::App::CGIBin -e 'builder {
    mount "/" => Plack::App::CGIBin->new(root => ".")->to_app;
    mount "/" => Plack::App::Directory->new({ root => "." })->to_app;
}'
```

is necessary, but mounting to the same path actually does not work in Plack 0.9985, or I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: OK, I find it really difficult to do the conversion. I think I need a vps to deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

I did not try it but This sounds like what you want.  Its bugzila deployed to a cloud stackato.
You can join Stackato then deploy the bugzilla sample.
https://github.com/Stackato-Apps/bugzilla

Comment: Note the [psgi.patch](https://github.com/Stackato-Apps/bugzilla/blob/master/psgi.patch) file, which might help here.